# I just added a contextment to the listBox when clicking the mouse right button but it dosen't work properly

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code.
In Form1 Load event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.Items != null && listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        listBox1.Select();
        label4.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string startTag = "Url: ";
        string endTag = " ---";
        int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
        int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
        int index = 0;
        index = label4.Text.IndexOf(startTag, index);
        int start = index + startTagWidth;
        index = label4.Text.IndexOf(endTag, start + 1);
        string g = label4.Text.Substring(start, index - start);
        label4.Text = g;
        mainUrl = g;
        listboxContextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
        listboxContextMenu.Opening += new CancelEventHandler(listboxContextMenu_Opening);
    }
}
```

Then the listBox mouseDown event:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
        {
            if (index == listBox1.SelectedIndex)
            {
                listboxContextMenu.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the Opening event:

```
private void listboxContextMenu_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //clear the menu and add custom items
    listboxContextMenu.Items.Clear();
    listboxContextMenu.Items.Add(string.Format("Edit - {0}", listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()));
}
```

What it does is that when I click on a specific item in the listBox on the mouse right buttin it's showing the contextMenu.

The problem is that the contextMenu show up all the time on the screen on the top left corner not the Form but the screen top left corner.

Second problem is that the contect menu show up only on the second time I click the selected item.
When im running my program the first item in the listBox is already selected and yet the contect menu show up only when I click twice on the item. After that I click once each time but first time when running my program I need to click twice on my right button click.

How can I fix these two problems ?

Comment: Why have you tagged ASP.NET in a winforms app?

Comment: @TimSchmelter it wasn't the OP who did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `MouseUp Event` instead of `MouseDown Event`

```
    private void listBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
            if (index == - 1) return;
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
            listboxContextMenu.Show(listBox1, listBox1.PointToClient(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position));
        }
    }
```

Comment: spajce two things. First when im running the program and the first item is already selected in the listBox when im doing right click button with the mouse nothing happen only when I make it again. That happen only when im running first time the program. Second thing is if I make right click mouse button on any place on the listBox it will work but I want it to work only on the selected item/index and not on any place/space of the listBox.

Comment: spajce no not working yet. I can make right click button on allover the listBox area and still need to click twice first time running the program . if you need the rest of the code but it's up on my question. In Form1 I did listBox1.Select(); to select the first item automatic when running the program and I have the oprning event.

Comment: i see the problem.. why dont you try to create a contextMenu and event in design time?

Comment: spajce ok you right I will make it in the designer. And what could be a solution for the two problems ?

Comment: first, try to create a `contextMenu` and `opening event` and for `listBox1_MouseUp event` in the design time and apply my answer.

Comment: spajce ok I did it in the designer the only thing that is not working now as I wanted is that everywhere on the listBox1 surface I click right mouse button it's showing the contextMenuStrip and I need it to be only when the mouse is over on the selected item. First to select with the mouse click left button the item then right click on it if make right click on it on any other place it should not work.

Comment: since i tried my answer in my listBox and has a default items. i have no idea what did you mean by that about in the another problem.